# @DBRef Lazy loading is not working

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring data mongodb, i trying to load entities lazy using db reference annotation of spring data mongodb,but it is not working.
still entity is loaded eagerly,what am i doing wrong here?

My preference domain

```
public class Preference extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    User user;

    MetadataEnum preferenceType;


    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


    public MetadataEnum getPreferenceType() {
        return preferenceType;
    }


    public void setPreferenceType(MetadataEnum preferenceType) {
        this.preferenceType = preferenceType;
    }


    public List<Subtype> getSubtypes() {
        return subtypes;
    }


    public void setSubtypes(List<Subtype> subtypes) {
        this.subtypes = subtypes;
    }

    List<Subtype> subtypes = new ArrayList<Subtype>();


    boolean enableSearch;

}
```

When i load preference domain,user entity loaded also.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working with 'spring-data-mongo-1.6.3'. And instead of the db reference loading eagerly, it is properly loading with a proxy object. I guess you might want to check once again.

Cheers